# Issue in reading avi files with OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video

I am trying to read a avi files using this chunk of code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    print ret, frame

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I got this output:

```
False None
```

and this error:

```
error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: error means that frame is not 3 or 4 channels, so you cannot use that color conversion code - however probably codec is not supported by opencv so frame is empty. you want want to use ffmpeg or gstreamer for video io

Comment: I followed your advice and used ffmpeg, thank you!